# in MYSQL how do I get key-value pairs from JSON without having to specify keys?

Tags: mysql, json

in most languages it's a simple task, for each key-value pair print keyname, value. I don't want to specify a key name for each pair, just get all of them. But I can't seem to find a way to do it in MySQL. For example:

```
create table myjson (icol JSON);  
INSERT INTO myjson VALUES('{"tmpdir":"/tmp"}');  
select JSON_VALUE(icol,'$.tmpdir') `with_key`  
, JSON_VALUE(icol,'$') `without key`  
,JSON_KEYS(icol,'$') `just key`  
from myjson;
```

I'd want to return a columnar data set of
key_name value
"tmpdir" "/tmp"

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
select j.key_name, 
  json_unquote(json_extract(icol, concat('$.', j.key_name))) as value
from myjson cross join json_table(json_keys(icol,'$'), '$[*]' 
  columns (key_name text path '$')) j;
+----------+-------+
| key_name | value |
+----------+-------+
| tmpdir   | /tmp  |
+----------+-------+
```

Comment: thanks, I see I was pretty far from a solution. was missing the concat in json_extract and json_keys in json_table...

Comment: Using JSON in MySQL makes data management more difficult. I recommend using normal rows and columns. If you want to store a JSON payload in the database, fine, but treat it as a single data value, not something to pick apart or manipulate with SQL expressions.